# Jquery looking for widget to hold multiple string values separated by white space or comma as object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, textfield

I am using latest version of jQuery (2.0.3).

I am looking for widget looks like text field, when you enter value separated by 'white space' or comma each separated value turns to be object with 'x' button. and it stays until you backspace or click 'x' to remove that object.

I have seen that kind of widgets but I am unable to find one on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ALOT of plugins like that.

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

ETC ETC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure to understand your question, but somenting like this:
[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should take a look at [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
mylistofitems = []
$("#myinputtext").change(function(){
  // Read value
  // if lastchar = " "
     // Add to mylistofitems
  // Create proper divs (deleting old ones and recreating if u want, by keeping a list of names)
  // Change left padding of myinputtext
});
```